# How to convert a python code into a 32 bit application on a 64 bit machine

Tags: python, 32bit-64bit, converters

I've downloaded python 3.10 32 bits and tried to convert it again but still, it came out as 64 bit. I used pycharm to code and pyinstaller to convert.

Comment: Are you sure you run pyinstaller from 32-bit version of Python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have no idea what you mean. When you say "I've downloaded python 3.10 32 bits and tried to convert it again but still, it came out as 64 bit.", ***what is "it"***? What exactly are you doing with pyinstaller, and what do you mean about "converting"? And why do you *want to* create a 32-bit executable? (Why do you want to create an executable at all?)

Comment: Yes, I re-read. I still have questions; see edit.

Comment: "it" is the application I converted. I tried to convert a python code into a 32 bit application to run on 32 bit system from a 64 bit system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want to generate the 32-bit app by pyinstaller, but failed.
Because you used 64-bit python to run pyinstaller.

To solve this, you can install Python3(32-bit version) in a new environment and use Python3(32-bit version) to invoke pyinstaller to generate the 32-bit app.

Comment: what do you mean by "new environment"

Comment: See https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/, you can build an new environment in conda.

Answer (score 0):

Python is usually an interpreted language; correct Python code will run on any machine that has the interpreter installed, with no modifications. It sounds as if what you want to do is to take code that you wrote on a 64 bit system and use Pyinstaller to compile it into an executable for a 32 bit system. The easiest way to do that is to install Pyinstaller on the target machine, put your code there, and run Pyinstaller; the [Pyinstaller manual](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) explicitly says that it's not a cross-compiler.